# help with probability

Tags: probability

I have two coins. One is fair, and one is unfair (H with probability 2/5, T with probability 3/5). I choose a coin at random and ﬂip it, and get H. What is the probability the coin I chose is the fair coin? What if I ﬂip the coin again, and again get H–what is the probability I chose the fair coin then?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please show your work. We are not answering machines and it is considered standard to show your attempts at a solution. People are more encouraged to help if you do so.

Comment: I tried to do a tree diagram. picking a fair coin probability is 1/2 and the probability of choosing H is 1/2 so choosing a fair coin and H probability would be 1/4 I think.

Comment: The overall approach though is to use $P(\text{fair coin} | H) = P(\text{fair coin and H})/P(H)$. Namely, the probability is $\frac{1/4}{1/4+1/5} = 5/9$. About your method, you're solving a different question. We're not dealing with the probability of both events happening, but rather that **if** you get H, **then** what are the odds that you initially picked a fair coin.

Comment: Right, so conditional probability applies here

Comment: Yes. As for the second part, I hope everything is clear?

Comment: yes it is i understand it now

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  calculate P(choose fair)P(fair comes heads) and P(choose biased)P(biased comes heads).  The chance you have the fair coin is $\frac {\text{ P(choose fair)P(fair comes heads)}}{\text{ P(choose fair)P(fair comes heads)+P(choose biased)P(biased comes heads)}}$

Can you see how to modify this for the second part?

Comment: I see it but i'm not sure if you have to include the first probability for the second flip

Comment: It is very similar, instead of fair gives H, use fair gives HH, instead of biased gives H, use biased gives HH.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of choosing fair coin = Probability of choosing unfair coin = $\frac{1}{2}$

For question 1:
Using bayes theorem,
 Probability of choosing fair coin when head occurs $=\frac{\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{5}} = \frac{5}{9}$

And for question 2:

We have to take all cases such that head occurs on both coins (case when both are fair and head occurs, cases when one is fair and other is unfair and head occurs and case when both are unfair and head occurs.

Probability of choosing fair coin when head occurs 
$\frac{\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{2}{5}}=\frac{25}{81}$